# Ubuntu live session problem from, in transferring files from password protected account in Windows

Tags: windows-10, live-cd

Long story and I've made a couple of posts about it in Superuser, but with my admin account locked and no way of accessing it (I've tried a bunch of methods), a suggestion of using Ubuntu live session was helpful in that I was able to access some of my files in my admin account.  However the strangest thing happens in that when I transfer those files to my guest account (that's how I'm accessing internet right now) and I'm not in the live session anymore, the folders holding the files becomes unaccessible: "corrupt or unreadable". I tried to put them in public folder instead of guest account and same thing.  I don't know what's going on.

Comment: I'm in the chatroom now

Comment: I think I know what the issue is